# Does the order of table references matter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Consider the following simplified query:

```
SELECT * FROM x, y JOIN z ON z.id = x.bean_id
```

It doesn't work; MySQL (Technically MariaDB 10.0.21) gives the error:

```
Unknown column 'x.bean_id' in 'on clause'
```

However, if I switch the order of the table references (`x, y` becomes `y, x`), then the query executes successfully:

```
SELECT * FROM y, x JOIN z ON z.id = x.bean_id
```

What's going on here?

Comment: P.S. fwiw, I think I could fix the problem by rewriting the original query to use `JOIN` throughout instead of a mix of `JOIN` and selecting from multiple tables. Still, this seems weird to me; I'm curious what is causing the problem.

Comment: Hmm... Now that I'm thinking about it more, maybe I need to think of `JOIN` in terms of being a binary operator. `y, x JOIN z` works, but I wonder if `x JOIN z ... , y` would work as well. I've never considered throwing a `JOIN` in to the middle of a table references list

Comment: Looks like `SELECT * FROM x JOIN z ON z.id = x.bean_id, y` works! Kind of a funky looking query, though...

Comment: With this simple example, you seem to have answered your own question. In summary, never use comma style JOINs, and definitely NEVER intermix comma joins and regular joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it matters.

`However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than that of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.`

Pls see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html for more details.

BTW, Why do you use x,y,z to stand for your situation, but the error message is orignal column name 'bean_id'?

Comment: These are all great answers (upvoted them all), but I've selected this one as the best answer since it has a spot-on-relevant reference to the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate error can be relieved by wrapping the `x, y` implicit cross join in parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM (x, y) JOIN z ON z.id = x.bean_id
```

I think the error has to do with ambiguity as to which join `y` belongs.

### Demo

But you are mixing the old school implicit join syntax with the modern (and proper) explicit join syntax.  Don't do that, in fact don't use the old join syntax at all.  Instead, always use explicit joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
INNER JOIN y
    ON x.id = y.id
INNER JOIN z
    ON z.id = x.bean_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks suspect in that there is an implicit join between `x` and `y`:

```
SELECT * FROM y, x JOIN z ON z.id = x.bean_id
```

Is there a missing join condition between `x` and `y`?

Or is it your intention to do a cross join between `x` and `y`, and have a join condition purely on whether `z`? A cross join is a relatively unusual kind of join.

If the latter, I would rewrite the query to make it clear, for example:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM 
    x 

CROSS JOIN
    y

INNER JOIN 
    z 
    ON (z.id = x.bean_id)
```

The above is exactly equivalent to your current code which you say is working.

Alternatively, if there is a condition missing from the join between `x` and `y`, then it would take the following form:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM 
    x 

INNER JOIN
    y
    ON (/*INSERT MISSING JOIN EXPRESSION BETWEEN x AND y HERE*/)

INNER JOIN 
    z 
    ON (z.id = x.bean_id)
```